# Submitting form using Casperjs Error

Tags: web-scraping, casperjs

I'm trying to scrape products with color and size variations.
Every variation is a **form** and to get the next variation I'm clicking on radio button and it is doing a form submit action on each click.

I have tried to click it using

```
1. “casper.getElementsInfo(element)[0].click();”
2. “document.querySelectorAll(element)[2].click();”
3. “casper.thenClick('element');”
4. “casper.evaluate(function(){document.querySelectorAll(element)[2].click();});”
```

After every click I'm doing a casper wait for 8 seconds !

**So here is my problem Casperjs is getting error after clicking the next color/size**

```js
var casper = require('casper').create({
    viewportSize: {
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080
    },
    pageSettings: {
        loadImages: false,
        loadPlugins: false
    }
});
casper.then(function () {
    self.thenOpen("https://scubapro.johnsonoutdoors.com/fins/fins/seawing-nova-fin-full-foot", function () {
        casper.then(function () {
            var varitoinCount = document.querySelectorAll('div#edit-attributes-field-swatch-taxonomy > div input').length;
            var i = 0;
            casper.repeat(varitoinCount + 1, function () {
                try {
                    document.querySelectorAll('div#edit-attributes-field-swatch-taxonomy > div input')[i].click();
                    casper.log('we got to anhoter variatoin ...' + i);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
                i++;
            });

        });
    });
});
try {
    casper.run();
} catch (e) {
    consol.log("Error..... " + e);
}
```

> (TypeError: undefined is not a constructor )

And btw when I'm doing the same thing in a console it works fine

Comment: Provide the actual code you are using and website which you are trying to scrape.

Comment: @MarioNikolaus,
Here you have a link to a product with variations
[link](https://scubapro.johnsonoutdoors.com/fins/fins/seawing-nova-fin-full-foot)
so i want to loop to all products and their variations  so what is the best way to get the to all colors and sizes !
Thanks a lot ....

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that accessing DOM **is not possible** in Casper environment. You should switch to browser environment to execute your DOM selectors by using Casper's [evaluate](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) method. Basically it used to get some information from within browser or to manually do some actions with javascript. To understand it you have a whole section dedicated for that in official documentation.

[image]

That being said, I amended your code to properly click on different color variation inputs.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  viewportSize: {
      width: 1920,
      height: 1080
  },
  pageSettings: {
      loadImages: false,
      loadPlugins: false
  }
});
casper
.start()
.thenOpen("https://scubapro.johnsonoutdoors.com/fins/fins/seawing-nova-fin-full-foot", function () {
  var varitoinCount = this.evaluate(function() {
    return document.querySelectorAll('div#edit-attributes-field-swatch-taxonomy > div input').length;
  });
  var i = 0;
  this.repeat(varitoinCount + 1, function() {
    this.evaluate(function(iterator) {
      document.querySelectorAll('div#edit-attributes-field-swatch-taxonomy > div input')[i].click();
    }, i);
    i++;
  })
});
try {
  casper.run();
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Error..... " + e);
}
```

However it still doesn't change the color since website(for some reason) needs to take 2 clicks to change the color and I suggest that you throw in some waitFor functions to be sure that color has changed.